# Spring JdbcTemplate limit query result to 15 rows

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and JdbcTemplate to query simple table.

I execute following queries:

- `select * from products`
- `select * from products limit 200 offset 0`
- `select * from products where ... limit 200 offset 0`.

All above queries returns 15 rows or less(when `where` is used). Does anybody know where this limit(15) can be configured?

I have added following properties

```
spring.jdbc.template.fetch-size=300
spring.jdbc.template.max-rows=300
```

but this doesn't work for me.

PS. I use PostgreSQL 12

**EDIT 1**

```
    public List<Product> getList(final ProductFilter filter) {
        final String query = filterToWhereClause(filter);
        final String where = query.isEmpty() ? "" : " where " + query;
        final String sql = String.format("select * from products %s order by id limit %d offset %d", where, filter.getSize(), filter.getPage() * filter.getSize());

        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (resultSet, rowNumber) -> productRowMapper(resultSet));
    }

    private static String filterToWhereClause(final ProductFilter filter) {
        return Stream.of(
            like("name", filter.getName()),
            gte("price", filter.getPriceFrom()),
            lte("price", filter.getPriceTo()),
            gte("total", filter.getTotalFrom()),
            lte("total", filter.getTotalTo())
        )
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
    }

    private static Product productRowMapper(final ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        return resultSet.next()
            ? Product.of(resultSet.getInt("id"), resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"), resultSet.getBigDecimal("total"))
            : null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the number of rows in db?

Comment: @Lemmy I have 29 rows

Comment: Could you please edit the post to display the code

Comment: @SebastianC. please check code

Comment: I did not find any suspicious in your code.. What I recommend is to enable sql logging by adding spring.jpa.show-sql=true in your application.properties and see how jpa is executing the query.

Comment: Problem in my `productRowMapper` function :(
I manually call `ResultSet.next()` while I shouldn't. Spring Jdbc calls it for me. As a result I get only each second row((